# Using RecursiveIteratorIterator with namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, iterator, standard-library, spl

My problem is that when I'm using namespaces, I can't use the RecursiveIteratorIterator Class of the Standard PHP Library.
The following code :

```
<?php namespace mynamespace;

    $arr = Array("abc", Array("def", "ghi", Array("jkl")));
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
    $result = iterator_to_array($it, false);

?>
```

Returns:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mynamespace\RecursiveIteratorIterator' not found in ...

Comment: `new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));`  -  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: Oh thank you write is as answer and I will tick it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reference the global namespace with `\`:

```
$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
```

Or you can import them into the current namespace with `use`:

```
namespace mynamespace;
use RecursiveIteratorIterator;
use RecursiveArrayIterator;
```

See [**Using namespaces: Basics**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) for details.